# Jmeter OAuth Plugin

Tags: oauth, jmeter

I am using jmeter to perform some load testing. this particular test will record how long it takes to get a response from a web service using OAUTH.

I have added the Jmeter Oauth plugin, set up my keys, url and data to be posted etc, however I keep getting an error message within my report

```
    Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
    Response message: Non HTTP response message: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 14
```

Has anyone had this error before or does anyone have a good guide on how to use the OAUTH plugin?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

when i get this error the problem was that i perfix the server name or ip 
with http 
so if you set server name or ip parameter with for example http://www.google.com you need
to replace it with www.google.co.il namely omit the http:// 
(you can set the protocol http in the protocol value of http request)